# Method cannot be applied to given types Required: int. Found: no arguments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods, arguments

I'm having issues with my app. I'm writing a method with a CountDownTimer and I'm passing an argument 'velocidadbpm' which is a variable with an integer.
When I compile I have the following error 
error: method reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer in class metronomo cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

This is the method
public class metronomo extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView numerobpm;
private TextView bpm;
private TextView variablevelocidadbpm;
private TextView nombreitaliano;
private RadioButton metronomoizq;
private RadioButton metronomoder;
private static SeekBar seekbarmetronomo;
private Button play;
private int velocidadbpm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_metronomo);

    variablevelocidadbpm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.variablevelocidadbpm);
    nombreitaliano = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombreitaliano);
    numerobpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numerobpm);
    bpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bpm);
    metronomoizq = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.metronomoizq);
    metronomoder = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.metronomoder);
    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer();
        }
    });
    seekbarmetronomo = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbarmetronomo);
    seekbarmetronomo.setProgress(0);
    seekbarmetronomo.incrementProgressBy(25);
    seekbarmetronomo.setMax(250);
    //Indica en el TextView nombreitaliano El ritmo del metrónomo.
    seekbarmetronomo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progress / 1;
            progress = progress * 1;
            velocidadbpm = progress;
            //Cambia el número de BPM en el TextView numerobpm
            numerobpm.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
            //Guarda en la variable velocidad bpm el número de BPM para ser utilizado como parámetro
            variablevelocidadbpm.setText(Integer.toString(velocidadbpm));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });



    }



public void reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer(int velocidadbpm) {
this.velocidadbpm = velocidadbpm;
int intervalo = velocidadbpm * 60000;


new CountDownTimer(60000, intervalo) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        reproducirSonido();
    }
    public void onFinish(){

    }
}.start();
}
```

Comment: Post your class `metronomo`

Comment: There is posted

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `int` value to call **`reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer`**. Problem is in your `onClick`, update this.

```
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer();
        }
    });
```

Invoke the function with some value. In **Android Studio** you see a red mark besides this line. I don't know, how could you miss that?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function with no arguments.
Here

```
reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer(**Pass an int here**);
```

While your function needs an argument.

```
public void reproducirSonidoCountDownTimer(int velocidadbpm)
```